# Mysql search by multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating search option using php .I want to do search when user give multiple fields according to given fields i need fetch records from the database.to get clear idea about what i need to do below is the interface of the search option

[when user click go in form submit i need to get user given filds and fetch record according to given search crieteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5sSg.png)

so i have looked many options and i found below as efficient

```
    $query = 'SELECT *
    FROM user
    WHERE 1 = 1 ';

    if(!empty($serviceNumber) )
    {
        $query .= ' and serviceNumber = ? ';
        $params[] = $serviceNumber;
    }
    if(!empty($name)) 
    {
        $query .= ' and userName = ? ';
        $params[] = $name;
    }
    if(!empty($status)) 
    {
        $query .= ' and status = ? ';
        $params[] =$status;
    }
    if(!empty($params)) 
    {

        $sth->execute($params);
        $dbh->prepare($query);
        $result= mysqli_query($dbcon,$sth);
                if(!$result ) 
                {
                  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());

                }
    }
     else
    {
        echo 'Missing Values';
    }
```

> but i got $sth as undefined variable so is there efficient way or can i correct this error.if any one can help appreciated.

Comment: As per code you don't have $ssh variable in your code, can you please add full code here, if possible?

Comment: This is completely wrong; you are mixing up mysqli and PDO syntax and the order of the statements doesn't make any sense. So even if you were to define `$sth` correctly using the `prepare` line, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya What are you talking about? Where do you see a `$ssh` variable?

Comment: Have you seen the how mysqli statement works. Follow the link. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Oh sorry, My mistake it is $sth :)

Comment: @MaulikSavaliya yes and `$sth` is used in his code.

Comment: actually i didnt know how to do this i follow previusly asked question n do this so how do execute the query as per user given details

Comment: $sth not i have used in my code i used it only in this given code 1st time

Answer (score 0):

This code would work (even if you reverse the wrong order prepare an execute called in) only with PDO.

For mysqli you have to always bind your values explicitly, which is a distinct pain in the back. Luckily, since PHP version 5.6 [there is an argument unpacking operator that helps](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison#splat):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$types = str_repeat('s', count($params));
$statement->bind_param($types, ...$params);
$statement->execute();
$res = $statement->get_result();
$data = $res->fetch_all();
```

however, if your PHP version doesn't meet this requirement or get_result() function is not supported, I would strongly suggest to forget about mysqli and turn to PDO. Which will make your code a lot simpler and - which is way more important - would work with any PHP version regardless:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute($params);
$data = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: can you please refer the way i do from below answer.i cannot fetch data